# Issues with Claymore cannot build OpenCL for GPU 0

Tags: claymore

Currently I am unable to start mining using **Claymores** software. I followed **CryptoBadgers** guide completely:

http://www.cryptobadger.com/2017/04/build-ethereum-mining-rig-linux/

I keep getting this error when I try to initiate my miner by typing this command

```
./miner.sh

ETH: 1 pool is specified
Main Ethereum pool is us1.ethermine.org:4444

Catalyst 15.12 is REQUIRED for best performance and compatibility
For Polaris cards, use latest drivers
At least 16 GB of Virtual Memory is required for multi-GPU systems
Make sure you defined GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
Be careful with overclocking, use default clocks for first tests
Press "s" for current statistics, "0".."9" to turn on/off cards, "r" to reload pools, "e" or "d" to select current pool
OpenCL initializing...

AMD Cards available: 1
GPU #0: Pitcairn, 3072 MB available, 8 compute units
POOL/SOLO version
Cannot build OpenCL program for GPU 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am currently using a **Radeon R9 370** for a GPU and I installed the following driver:

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx

This is also on **Xubuntu 16.04.2**.

**Miner settings:**

```
#!/bin/sh
export GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR=0
export GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE=100
export GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS=1
export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
export GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT=100

./ethdcrminer64 -epool us1.ethermine.org:4444 -ewal 4d562bdab44696995251dd7bf743bbaf09b8b16e.Miner01 -epsw x -mode 1 -tt 68 -allpools 1
```

Can anyone explain what I have to do to fix the following error?

```
Cannot build OpenCL program for GPU 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Have you try to remove `export GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR=0`

Comment: @SteffelFenix hey Steffel yes, I tried doing that as well. It appears that linux doesn't have drivers to support my card. However, I ended up using Windows 10. Drivers and everything works fine... but low MH/s

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, it worked when I deleted these ones :

```
export GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR=0
export GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE=100
export GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS=1
export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
export GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
```

also I did not use start.sh, I used console with these:

```
./ethdcrminer64 -epool eth-eu1.nanopool.org:9999 -ewal 0x<wallet>.<rig>/<mail> -epsw x -mode 1 -ftime 10
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have the AMDPRO driver installed from http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx
2. Test your driver version by executing

   ```
   dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
   ```
3. Many cards do not support the **GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR=0** setting under Ubuntu.

Remove this setting from your environment or your miner.sh file:

```
    #export GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR=0
    export GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE=100
    export GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS=1
    export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
    export GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
    ./ethdcrminer64 <your parameters here>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with my claymore software. I downloaded and installed the microsoft c++ runtime for claymore (mining version) and it was worked. 
http://how-to-mine.com/softwares/runtimes/Microsoft_C++_Runtime.zip 
This solution worked for me.try it. i hope you can solve your problem